# Using boost::asio is there a portable way to find out free port number

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, port

I'm currently trying to figure out a way to find the number of a free port to establish a connection,  ideally with boost::asio. This port number would then be used to listen on (and only then can I open a socket).

Roughly, is there a way to do

```
   tcp::resolver::query query("localhost", port);
```

where the port is left blank (setting it to 0 doesn't work)

None of the options seen previously were portable, or efficient.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to just let the OS pick a random available port at the moment that the socket is being bound to a port.  Tell the socket to bind to port 0, then query the socket for the actual port it bound to if successful.  Do not try to find a port ahead of time and then bind to it, that introduces a race condition.  Another socket could snag the port after you found it but before you could bind it.

Comment: That was my initial goal, but simply passing it 0 doesn't work, as stated in the question

Comment: To clarify: count << endpoint.port()  << endl; 
  cout << endpoint.address().to_string() << endl; 

Return 0 and the localhost address. I need to be able to advertise this uri and therefore need to know the exact port number

Comment: how are you initializing/obtaining `endpoint`?  Please show your actual code.

Comment: I have found what the issue was. The correct way to do this was tcp::resolver::query query("localhost",""); rather than passing 0

Comment: The 3rd party library I'm using requires a specified port.

Comment: @Inverse that means you aren't interested in a random free port anyhow and this question is irrelevant to your situation.